# HashLocationStrategy does not produce # locations when routing?

Tags: angular2-routing

I'm running the Angular 2 beta.0 and I'm messing around with routing. Here's what I have

AppComponent:

```
import {Component, provide} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {FORM_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/common';
import {Http, Response, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {RouteConfig, Location, LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';

import {HomeComponent} from './components/home';
import {RowsComponent} from './components/rows';
import {ColumnsComponent} from './components/columns';
import {TableComponent} from './components/table';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  templateUrl: '/app/views/root.html',
  providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]
})
@RouteConfig([
  {path:'/',       name: 'Home',     component: HomeComponent},
  {path:'Rows',    name: 'Rows',     component: RowsComponent},
  {path:'Columns', name: 'Columns',  component: ColumnsComponent},
  {path:'Table',   name: 'Table',    component: TableComponent}
])
class AppComponent {
  public title = 'Responsive Layout';
  public SelectedTab = 'Home';

  constructor(location: Location) {
    //location.go('Rows');
  }
}

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})
]);
```

Every tutorial and API reference seems to point to me doing it just like I have above. I also have `<base href="/app/" />` in the head of my index.html. Here are my `RouterLinks`

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li [class.active]="SelectedTab=='Home'"><a [routerLink]="['Home']" (click)="SelectedTab='Home'">Home</a></li>
    <li [class.active]="SelectedTab=='Rows'"><a [routerLink]="['Rows']" (click)="SelectedTab='Rows'">Rows</a></li>
    <li [class.active]="SelectedTab=='Columns'"><a [routerLink]="['Columns']" (click)="SelectedTab='Columns'">Columns</a></li>
    <li [class.active]="SelectedTab=='Table'"><a [routerLink]="['Table']" (click)="SelectedTab='Table'">Table</a></li>
  </ul>
```

The routing behaves like it should. I get no errors. When I click on one of these entries in the bootstrap nav-bar I see that the views have switched out and are showing the proper templates and that their Components have run and are being bound to. However, despite using `HashLocationStrategy` in my `bootstrap(...)` call, the URLs are still "HTML5 Style": `localhost:8080/app/Rows` when it should be `localhost:8080/app/#/Rows`.

I believe I need to use the old # based way if I want my users to be able to bookmark a particular view and come back to it. If I allow for `/app/Rows` then refreshing the page causes a 404 because `Rows` doesn't exist in the `app` folder.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I tried your code, it works

my code below:

boot.ts

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {provide} from 'angular2/core';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component'
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS, LocationStrategy, 
        HashLocationStrategy,
        PathLocationStrategy,
        APP_BASE_HREF, } from 'angular2/router'


bootstrap(AppComponent,[
     ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
     provide(APP_BASE_HREF, { useValue: '/' }),
     provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass : HashLocationStrategy})
]);
```

-

app.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';

@Component({
  selector:'second',
  template: `<h1>second</h1>`
})

export class SecondComponent{}

@Component({
   selector: 'home',
   template: `<h1>hello</h1>`
})

export class HomeComponent{}

@Component({
   directives : [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
   selector: 'my-app',
   template: 
    `<a [routerLink]="['Home']">home</a>
     <a [routerLink]="['Second']">Second</a>
     <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `
})


 @RouteConfig([
   {path :'/' ,name: 'Home', component: HomeComponent},
   {path :'/second', name : 'Second', component : SecondComponent}

  ])

 export class AppComponent { }
```

I find your problem, delete this line

```
providers : [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]
```

the details I don't know why, maybe angular can't not process when you are using ROUTERPROVIDERS twice, looking forward someone can help u

Comment: Yeah, removing the provider fixed it. I'm not sure why, but that made all the difference.

Comment: same here, removed router_providers from the component performing the routerLink. Router_providers seems to only be uses in bootstrap component.

Answer (score 3):

As per Angular 2 final release you have to include `LocationStrategy` to use `HashLocationStrategy` class by putting it inside providers of main @NgModule
by doing `{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}`

**app.module.ts**

```
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {
  LocationStrategy,
  HashLocationStrategy
} from '@angular/common';
@NgModule({
   imports: [...], //put module to import here
   declarations: [...], //put all component, pipe & directive
   exports: [...], //module to export
   //providers should reside here
   providers: [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}]
})
class AppModule {}
```

Comment: @arn-arn Personally I spent 1-2 hour on the same, so I thought to add answer. Glad to know that it helped, Thanks :)